# Where are influence and mapping settings of a texture saved?

Tags: materials, texturing

I just did the following:

I created one material and one texture. I applied this texture to 5 slots and, which is nice, can assign different settings to each instance of the texture (influence, mapping etc).

Does that mean texture slots are a data block? It can't be in either the texture or the material, since I only have one of each. How is that organized internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right if you switch the Properties View to Datablocks you can examine the datastructure.

You find the per slot settings ([Texture Layers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures)) under /Materials/*MaterialName*/Textures /*TextureName*.
Each texture slot has its own settings.

[image]

How the different settings influence the resulting material is controled by the influence sliders of the checked properties and the [Blend Mode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Influence/Material/Blending_Modes) setting.